# Application wrapper for Mac app to log open and close times for files (launch using double click)

Tags: python, macos, video, logging, double-click

Here's my specific problem. I use Mplayer OSX to open video files. I want to do the following: when I double click a video file, it opens in Mplayer OSX but additionally it also logs the name of the file (plus time, etc) to some log file. The main problem is that I want all this to happen on double clicking the video file.

I searched SO and found some answers to doing this with Java. I prefer Python. I found this: [double click a file to run python script. how to get that file as an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880130/double-click-a-file-to-run-python-script-how-to-get-that-file-as-an-input) but there are no answers for OSX (I tried the equivalent of the Windows answer but it didn't work).

Comment: Just to clarify: you are looking for a way (on Mac OS X) to open your python script on double-clicking any video file?

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a programming question (unless you want to talk about how to open `Mplayer` from within python). Maybe ask this over at apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try the following:

1. Pack your python script (that starts `MPlayer` and logs the time for you) as an application package for Mac OS X. You can do that with: [`py2app`](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/)

   ```
   # install py2app
   pip install -U py2app

   # this goes into your setup.py
   from setuptools import setup
   setup(
       app=["myscript.py"],
       setup_requires=["py2app"],
   )

   # this is how you build your app
   python setup.py py2app
   ```
2. Open the Info dialog for any of your video files (Right-click > Get Info) and go to the *Open with:* section. Then select your own app and confirm with *Change All...*

Now all your files with extension `.avi` should launch your `py2app` packaged application. Repeat this for all video file types you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great so far!